# PHP code to make called image in loop into clickable link

Tags: php, image, loops, hyperlink, href

I'm running a PHP file that has the following code:

```
$loop .= '<div class="entry-thumb">';
$loop .= get_poster($item->ID, $img_size);
$loop .= '</div>';

$loop .= '<div class="entry-content">';

$loop .= '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink($item->ID) . '">' . $item->post_title . '</a></h2>';
```

I would like the "entry-thumb" class which calls upon an image to link to the same href location as the "entry-title" class.

Comment: So wrap the image in the same anchor tag you use for the title.

Comment: Didn't think it would be that easy, thanks!